# When to use accuracy_score with train_test_split VS. cross_val_score with kfolds?

Tags: machine-learning, cross-validation

I want to measure how well my predictive model performs so I can report the percentage for my project, but I'm not sure which of the scores to report, the one given when I used kfolds and cross_val_score, or the score given when I use train/test split and accuracy score?

Do I just choose the lower one no matter what?

If it matters, my dataset isn't too big, less than 500 points, but this is sort of a beginners project anyways.

Thanks

edit:

Option 1:

```
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, train_size=0.75, test_size=0.2, shuffle=True)
model = LogisticRegression()
model.fit(X_train, y_train)
y_pred = model.predict(X_test)
print(accuracy_score(y_test, y_pred) ## This is what I report
```

Option 2:

```
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, train_size=0.75, test_size=0.2, shuffle=True)
model = LogisticRegression()
cv = RepeatedKFold(n_splits=5, n_repeats=5)
scores = cross_val_score(model, X_train, y_train, scoring="accuracy", cv=cv)
print(mean(scores)) ## This is what I report
```

Comment: Are you doing any hyperparameter optimization?

Comment: @gunes Maybe I will in the future, but for now, no, I'm just analyzing the data and then applying some models to the data to see how well they work on their own. Should I use one if I am doing hp optimization and the other if I'm not?

Answer (score 1):

If you're not doing hyperparameter optimization or model selection, you don't need to do both cross_val_score and train/test split. Depending on your size of the dataset, I'd advise doing cross validation (possibly >10 folds and maybe leave-one-out if model executes quickly) and obtaining a performance metric that way. It's more robust than just a train/test split if the dataset is small.

Comment: Hmm okay, and what if I do choose to do hyperparameter optimization or model selection? Would I then switch to using Train/test split and accuracy_score?

And am I comparing these things correctly? I'm new to machine learning, but the things I'm comparing are in the same category of model evaluation, correct? And you need to choose one or the other?

Comment: If you need a final model to use for future data, then first train/test split and do HP on the training set using cross validation. You need to choose your performance metric yourself (e.g. accuracy, recall, precision etc), by setting `scoring` argument of `cross_val_score`. The choice of performance metric is independent of how you validate, i.e. cross validation or train/test split. See its doc page: https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.cross_val_score.html

Comment: I'm a little confused on what you mean by "validate". I made an edit, these are the 2 options that I have, you're saying go for option 2, correct?

Comment: @chung Neither of them. You should use `cross_val_score` directly with `X` and `y`. Second option wastes your test set. You could do the first one, but your dataset small, so CV is better.